# field should be editable from apex. how?

Tags: apex, read-only

I've a field read only from field accessibility for a profile. when i try to check that field from apex it will not editable.

i want this field should be editable by apex and not manually.

my apex class;

```
global class CreateOpty{

    WebService static Integer CreateOptywithps(String Id){

        ..........
    }
}
```

how can i do?

Comment: Assuming the field isn't a read-only data type, like a formula, you can indeed set the value in your class. Try including information about the error you're getting when you try to update the value, or the behavior you experience.

Comment: means by default it will update the read only field by apex class.

Comment: Are you calling this class through anonymous apex?

Comment: I'm calling this class from custom Button

Comment: From what you've described, this should be entirely possible. Where were you running into trouble?

Comment: when i try for user(not admin ), this will not updating my read only field from apex

Comment: Does that non-Admin profile have access to the class? Has it been enabled for the profile?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42750/discussion-between-amol-and-martin).